# phpMyAdmin working intermittently on Google Apps Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I followed [this tutorial](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/) to install phpMyAdmin a couple months ago on Google Apps Engine. It worked without issue until last Friday. Having changed no settings, I was greeted by the login screen and clicked "Go". After clicking, the screen went blank with no error and my logs show no errors. My website, which accesses the same database, had no issues reading and writing to the database. I checked everything I could and became so desperate that I created another Google Apps Engine Application and installed a fresh copy of phpMyAdmin and created a new database for it to access. It would still only show a blank page after clicking "Go". On the new account, I then installed SQLBuddy and had the exact same results, just a blank page after logging. Somewhere around Tuesday afternoon, I changed a minor setting and everything worked again. I then went back to my original phpMyAdmin installation and, even though I had changed nothing, it was working again. I assumed this was all some glitch on Google's side and continued work as usual.

Now today, I tried to access my phpMyAdmin database again, and now it's doing the exact same thing. There is still nothing wrong with my website, it's able to read and write to the same database, it's just phpMyAdmin that is showing a blank screen after clicking "Go".

Since the issue seems to rely with something internal to phpMyAdmin, are there any workarounds that I might be able to use to get past this new bug that keeps happening?

Comment: Thinking of a remedy rather than a workaround, probably Google should fix it but they don't monitor StackOverflow tags for bugs.  Please report a Defect at the [AppEngine Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues).

Comment: what do your application logs say?

Comment: And also anything relevant in the webserver error log?